# Side By Side Pages in Layout View?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

When working In layout View how do you make side by side pages. Two pages on the same screen. I have seen this done once so I know it is possible. Both pages were set up 8.5 by 11. I know you can use multiple pages with DDP but I would like two on the same screen so that I can have two different titles and Legends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot see multiple layouts with the out-of-the-box ArcGIS Desktop.

ArcMap supports only a single layout.  If you've seen it before I'd suggest that there may have been a third-party extension to allow it (or perhaps the Production Line Tool Set (PLTS) does it)

Alternatively ArcGIS Pro allows for multiple layouts which can be positioned side-by-side.

Please see [FAQ: Can ArcMap have multiple layout views?](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002910)

Answer (score 4):

Try to use two dataframes, perhaps is what you are looking for.
For each dataframe you can create different legends, maps name, layout symbols.

1-Insert-> New Dataframe

2-Switch to Layout than you will see two different views in same page, you can move, resize each of them.

Comment: Yeah I have tried it with new data frames and that will be a part of setting this up, but the one I had seen once had its own ruler and everything. You could also select either one to export.